# Missing Helper Error when executing query in cakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I have index.ctp in my Users which list all the users. I added a search input to search for a certain user.

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => false, 'type' => 'post']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('search', array('label' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Search users here...')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Search') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

and I have this condition where to see if there is a post request.

```
<?php
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
     $query = $this->Users->find('all', array('conditions' => array('users.name LIKE' => '%gol%')));
     $result = $query->first();
     echo $result->name;
} else {
?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($user->name) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($user->username) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($user->created) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($user->modified) ?></td>
        <td class="actions">
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id]) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I have a Missing Helper error. The message is : "UsersHelper could not be found."

Comment: please let me know yours file name.second block is in controller ?

Comment: seems you mixed the controller and the view code. You can't retrieving your data in the view. I suggest you to studythe cookbook and read about MVC pattern

Comment: @arilia I get it now, I made a search function in my UsersController and call the variable in my view... Thank you :D